# How to create tab pages content dynamically in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am using windows form to build an app that draws the form controls based on the connected device dynamically. So I have a tab control and when the user select tab3 for instance the tab page content will be drawing based on connected device for example add two text boxes and a button. How can I do this. I would like also to know how to position those controls after they are created.

```
private void tabPage3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox text = new TextBox();
    this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you just stated, you create your Controls like in your example. Positioning is achieved by the Left and Top Properties of your freshly created control. BUT, my advise is, it will be easier to use predefined UserControls and add them dynamically, because I think you don't have nearly unlimited types of devices.

If you are curious how Visual Studio Designer is creating those code, just look up Designer.cs in `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: can you explain how I should create a predefined  UserControls and add them dynamically, because in my case each device will have different controls so how can I achieve this.

Comment: Just add a new UserControl by right clicking in your project explorer and choose add->new control. How to determine which device your app is running is another topic, therefor you have to give really more info.